# Webpack Incomplete Chunk Encoding in Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, reactjs, docker, webpack

I have spent all weekend trying to figure out why i am getting the error `ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` when my application loads the bundled client side js file from webpack. I have just realized that Chrome is the only browser that throws this error. Why is this happening and how can I fix it ?

Comment: This is a Chome-specific warning caused by an interrupted chunked transfer. It's impossible for us to know why that is happening.

Answer (score 3):

It is known `Chrome problem`. According to `Chrome` and `Chromium` `bug trackers` there is no universal solution for this. This problem is not related with server type and version, it is right in Chrome.

Setting `Content-Encoding` header to `identity` solved this problem to me.